# Using a variable to find object by class or id

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want change the source of the images  using javascript variable, as in i have a variable "vp_active_row_count" which shows by number which ball is active. ("_a"=means active image source).

But i can't find any object using that lower javascript code. Is it even possible?

**Javascript**

```
var vp_active_row_count=2;
var test = '"#'+vp_active_row_count+'"';
$(test).attr('src','assets/img/vp_a.png');
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="vp_balls" style="width: 48px;">
    <img id="1" src="assets/img/vp_a.png">
    <img id="2" src="assets/img/vp.png">
    <img id="3" src="assets/img/vp.png">
</div>
```

Comment: `var test = '#'+vp_active_row_count;` although I really wouldn't use id as a counter.

Comment: why not:
var test = "#"+vp_active_row_count;
?

Comment: Change `var test` statement to `'#'+vp_active_row_count`

Comment: try using $(img[id=varname]).attr() something like this.

Comment: In `"#foo"`, the double quotes are **not** part of the value, they only indicate a string literal. The value is `#foo`. In your code, you are making the double quotes part of the value, so the selector is malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to quote twice! Quotes are for telling JS that this is a string, but jQuery doesn't need the extra pair

Comment: Thanks, tried alot of different stuff, dunno why didnt tried to removing stuff rather than adding!